# Store date from xml: which data structure I should use in java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm developing an app for Android and I need to read info from an xml file and to store in the app to use this data inside the app.
I parsed the xml file, now I need to save this value to a data structure, which structure do you suggest me?
In my iOS app I used 2 NSMutableArray that contains NSDictionary for every tag I found in my xml file.
I post here my start xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Programs>
    <Program programNumber="1" imgURL="http://www.photovideolife.com/userfiles/Placeholder%2001.jpg" description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit">
        <Episode pN="1" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo" date="29 Giu 2013" time1="14:30" time2="" channel="IRIS" channelLogo="http://indiscrezioni.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/logo_iris.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="1" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo" date="29 Giu 2013" time1="" time2="16:30" channel="La7" channelLogo="http://www.tabaccheriavenza.it/media/logo/la7.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="1" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="14:30" time2="" channel="IRIS" channelLogo="http://indiscrezioni.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/logo_iris.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="1" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="" time2="16:30" channel="la7" channelLogo="http://www.tabaccheriavenza.it/media/logo/la7.jpg">
        </Episode>
    </Program>
    <Program programNumber="2" imgURL="http://mesa.umich.edu/files/mesa/field/image/placeholder2.png" description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit">
        <Episode pN="2" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo 1" date="30 Giu 2013" time1="13:30" time2="" channel="Rai 1" channelLogo="http://i822.photobucket.com/albums/zz145/Mattelufregn/Loghi%20canali%20tv/70px-Logo_Rai_1_2010svg50x50.png">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="2" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo 1" date="30 Giu 2013" time1="" time2="18:30" channel="Rai 5" channelLogo="http://www.tuttotv.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/logo_rai5_50.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="2" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo 1" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="13:30" time2="" channel="Rai 1" channelLogo="http://i822.photobucket.com/albums/zz145/Mattelufregn/Loghi%20canali%20tv/70px-Logo_Rai_1_2010svg50x50.png">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="2" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo 1" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="" time2="18:30" channel="Rai 5" channelLogo="http://www.tuttotv.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/logo_rai5_50.jpg">
        </Episode>
    </Program>
    <Program programNumber="3" imgURL="http://wp.contempographicdesign.com/wp_paramount/wp-content/themes/paramount/images/image_placeholder_lrg.jpg" description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit">
        <Episode pN="3" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo 2" date="30 Giu 2013" time1="10:30" time2="" channel="Canale 5" channelLogo="http://www.mozaic.qa/logo/canale5.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="3" episodeNumber="1" transmissionName="Titolo 2" date="30 Giu 2013" time1="" time2="17:30" channel="Italia 1" channelLogo="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/3/30/Logo_Italia_1.svg/50px-Logo_Italia_1.svg.png">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="3" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo 2" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="10:30" time2="" channel="Canale 5" channelLogo="http://www.mozaic.qa/logo/canale5.jpg">
        </Episode>
        <Episode pN="3" episodeNumber="2" transmissionName="Titolo 2" date="01 Lug 2013" time1="" time2="17:30" channel="Italia 1" channelLogo="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/thumb/3/30/Logo_Italia_1.svg/50px-Logo_Italia_1.svg.png">
        </Episode>
    </Program>
</Programs>
```

Comment: I would use JAXB and let it handle your data structure. Putting everything into a massive `Map` really isn't the way to go. It's 2013...

Comment: I tried to so so: during the parse I put all info to a temporary map then I put the map in a List, but when I modify the map it modify the data in the List too.
I will try to use your solution, it's a library that I should add to my project?

Comment: It's a command line utility the is part of the JDK that compiles an an XML specification (schema) to java classes. At runtime you just ask it to load a matching document into the data structure.

Comment: Thank you! I will look in the web to understand how it works, but I guess it's not so hard to use

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a Java bean representing the xml data structure. And then using any xml/java mapping framework, you can easily marshal the xml to java bean and vice-versa. I am not sure whether JAXB can be a good choice on Android. You may try [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)